# Разбить строку на массив лексем используя StringBuffer

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Не используя StringTokenizer, разбить строку типа StringBuffer на массив лексем.
Целый день что-то пытаюсь, да не выходит.

Comment: А с чем связано такое странное ограничение? Учебное задание или собеседование?

Comment: Учебное задание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer`, если посмотреть на исходники, хранит свой буфер в виде массива `char[]`, а не в виде какого-то массива/списка исходных кусков полученных после `append()`, так что разбиение `StringBuffer` на лексемы ничем принципиально не отличается от разбиения строки `String` на лексемы.

А здесь выбор также достаточно ограничен: или использовать ваш нелюбимый `StringTokenizer` или `split()` или самому написать нечто вроде парсерчика (код не проверял - просто написал на коленках):

```
String s=myStringBuffer.toString(); //исходная строка
int start=0, end;
ArrayList<String> lexems=new ArrayList<String>; //складываем лексемы сюда
String separator=" "; //ваш разделитель - может быть любым
do {
   end=s.indexOf(separator, start);
   if(end >= 0) {
       lexems.add(s.substring(start, end);
       start=end+separator.length();
   }
   else
       lexems.add(s.substring(start));
} while(end >= 0);
```

Comment: Заменил ЭррэйЛист на массив Стринг, но выдает ошибку.
Я не правильно заменил?
Tokens[i] += (Str.substring(Start, End));

Comment: `tokens[i++]=str.substring(start, end));` и не нарушайте *java naming convention*!

Comment: спасибо огромное, сейчас буду пробовать :)

Comment: `int i = 0;
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  String[] tokens = new String[100];  
  StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("This is a test message");  
  String separator = " ";
  do {
   end = str.indexOf(separator, end);
   if(end >= 0) {
    tokens[i++] = (str.substring(start, end));
    start = end;
   }
   else
    tokens[i++] = (str.substring(start, end));
   }
  while(end >= 0);
  System.out.println(tokens[0]);`


Выдает ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at Main.main(Main.java:26)

Comment: Ну вообще то я не нанимался к вам компилятором:

        `String[] tokens=new String[100];
        StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer("This is a test message");
        String separator=" ";
        do {
            end=str.indexOf(separator, start);
            if(end >= 0)
            {
                tokens[i++]=(str.substring(start, end));
                start=end+separator.length();
            }
            else
                tokens[i++]=(str.substring(start));
            System.out.println("Token #"+i+"="+tokens[i-1]);
        } while(end >= 0);`

Comment: Извините, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте это

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("asd zxc 123 sdf");
String[] a = s.toString().split(" ")
```

Comment: Для пробела лучше `split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 1):

Немного не в тему вопроса, но как альтернативу можете использовать Google Guava, тогда все проще:

```
List<String> res = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.BREAKING_WHITESPACE).splitToList("asd zxc 123 sdf");
```